# How to convert vb.net property to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to convert the following segment of vb.net code into c# but I'm at a loss as to what I should be doing with the "ByVal Value".

```
  Public Property Area() As Point
    Get
      If _Area Is Nothing Then _Area = New Point

      Return _Area
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Point)
      _Area = Value
    End Set
  End Property
```

This is what I had it converted to but since the Value was not passed into the property I get the error "The name 'Value" does not exist in the current context":

```
public Point Area
{
    get
    {
        if (_Area == null)
            _Area = new Point();

        return _Area;
    }
    set
    {
        _Area = Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing this out in what you *think* the proper C# is? Or have you tried any automated tools yet?

Comment: I've tried to use a tool which yields this:

`public Point Area
{
    get
    {
        if (_Area == null)
            _Area = new Point();

        return _Area;
    }
    set
    {
        _Area = Value;
    }
}`

This will produce an error since Value is nowhere to be found. I looked into using keys to fix the issue but I wasn't quite able to grasp how to use them.

Comment: So then what's the problem? Do you not believe the tool is correct?

Comment: I recommend showing what C# you've tried (added to the overall post) rather than just asking for someone to convert it for you. Would also be great help to know *what* and *why* the C# provided doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my comment above but the compiler produces the error that "The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `value` should be lower-case. It's created automatically for the incoming value. Also, you may as well check for `value == null` in the setter as well, and not update `_Area` if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a valid C# implementation of the property. Note the lowercase [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value) keyword.

If you are using [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.7.2), this is a struct, so you have no need for the `is null` check, as it has a default value.

```
public Point Area
{
    get
    {
        if (_Area == null)
            _Area = new Point();

        return _Area;
    }
    set
    {
        _Area = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I used a generic example so I'm not using the System.Drawing.Point but I will keep that in mind for the future if I'm using a struct. I will mark this as the correct answer when the time permits. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If the `Point` constructor is trivial and the storage not worth thinking about (i.e., you could pre-initialize the `Area` property, you can use an *Auto-property*:

```
public Point Area { get; set; } = new Point();
```

At that point, the compiler will create a hidden backing variable (so you don't need your `_Area`) and everything is easier to read / easier to type.